# adding email id to aws account and giving access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I got one assignment from the company for DynamoDb and Elastic Seach. I have completed that. They have asked me to add their email id into my AWS account and give it access to DynamoDb and ES Instance.

I am not sure how should I do that. When I searched Google, it was showing to create AWS SOS. Also creating IAM role but for that will it require email id? I am not sure.

Please if someone can guide how to add another email id to my account and give access.

Thank you

Comment: You have to double-check with them what they want. I don't see how adding any email to anything in AWS could give them permissions.

Comment: It sounds like they want Console access, with an email address? In which case you can just create an additional IAM user (with the appropriate permissions) and send that email address an invite

Comment: Thanks Marcin and Bert Blommers for the answer. I created IAM user.